# Can i call another class constructor in a class which extends AppCompactDialogFragment in Android?

Tags: android

**i want to call stespRecord constructor in stepsDone where should i place the constructor call like StepsRecord rec = new StepsRecord(this);**

```
public class stepsDone extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    public Padomet data;
    public StepsRecord rec;
    private static final String TAG = "stepsDone";


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_steps_done, null);
        rec= new StepsRecord(this);
        builder.setView(view)

                .setNegativeButton("Do more", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Add to the List", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                       float g =data.get();
                       int d = data.getc();
                        Log.d(TAG, "HELLLOOOO1111"+g+"   uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu   "+d);



                        AddData(g,d);


                    }
                });

        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.tick2).into(imageView);
        return builder.create();
    }
    public void AddData(float arg1,int arg2) {       
          rec.addData(arg1, arg2);
    }
       
}
```

**this is the class whose constructor i want to call**

```
public class StepsRecord extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "PreviousRecord";

    private static final String COL1 = "Goal";
    private static final String COL2= "stepsTaken";



    public StepsRecord(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("+ COL1 + " TEXT,"
                + COL2 + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL(String.format("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS %s", TABLE_NAME));
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addData(float goal, int steps) {

         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String gooals = String.valueOf(goal);
        String stepstaken = String.valueOf(steps);
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //contentValues.put(COL1, strDate);
        contentValues.put(COL1, gooals);
        contentValues.put(COL2, stepstaken);


        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    }

    public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }


}
```

Your help would be appreciated... i have searched on this a lot but have not found any solution may be this is not possible or may be its possible .. if this is possible then please let me know or any other solution of doing.

Comment: the argument for `StepsRecord ` is `Context`, not `Fragment`, does something like `rec= new StepsRecord(this.getContext());` work? Or `rec= new StepsRecord(requireContext());`

Answer (score 0):

Now the constructor of `StepsRecord` needs a context as a parameter, and you are passing `this` which is referring to your `stepsDone` object which is a child of `Fragment`.

Now `Fragment` class doesn't extend `Context`, but the `Activity` class does.

**Keeping that in mind you can override `onAttach()` method in your `stepsDone` class and you will get a reference to the activity associated with your `stepsDone` class:**

```
public class stepsDone extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

public Padomet data;
public StepsRecord rec;
private static final String TAG = "stepsDone";


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

.......
.......

}

//here override the onAttach() and initialize the StepsRecord
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
super.onAttach(context);

//initialize here
rec= new StepsRecord(context);

}

.........
.........

}
```